# selecting individual xml node using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

I have a large  XML note with many  nodes.

is there a way that I can select only a single  node and all of its contents from the larger XML?

i am using sql 2005

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should use the [query() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) if you want to get a part of your XML.

```
declare @XML xml

set @XML = 
'
<root>
  <row1>
    <value>1</value>
  </row1>
  <row2>
    <value>2</value>
  </row2>
</root>
'

select @XML.query('/root/row2')
```

Result:

```
<row2>
  <value>2</value>
</row2>
```

If you want the value from a specific node you should use [value() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx).

```
select @XML.value('(/root/row2/value)[1]', 'int')
```

Result:

```
2
```

**Update:**

If you want to shred your XML to multiple rows you use [nodes() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).

To get values:

```
declare @XML xml

set @XML = 
'
<root>
  <row>
    <value>1</value>
  </row>
  <row>
    <value>2</value>
  </row>
</root>
'

select T.N.value('value[1]', 'int')
from @XML.nodes('/root/row') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
1
2
```

To get the entire XML:

```
select T.N.query('.')
from @XML.nodes('/root/row') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
<row><value>1</value></row>
<row><value>2</value></row>
```

Comment: nice, what if each of the row nodes were just <row> and i wanted to get each row node sequentially?

Comment: i want the results (<row2><value>2</value></row2>) not an integer but i want to get row1 xml chunk, then row2... for all rows

Comment: @kacalapy - Updated answer with how you shred XML to multiple rows.

Comment: Note that the XML for the nodes method example has <row> compared to <row1> of the first example higher up ..  i.e. not the same XML ..