# Select node from xml nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

there! there is a small xml.

```
Declare @xmlDoc xml = '
<ROW ID="471869" USER_ID="40161" NAME="James" CNT="2" />
<ROW ID="482047" USER_ID="40836" NAME="Nick" CNT="2" />
'
```

I'm selecting data via

```
SELECT x.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS ID,
       x.value('(@USER_ID)[1]', 'int') AS USER_ID,
       x.value('(@NAME)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS NAME,
       x.value('(@CNT)[1]', 'int') AS CNT,
       @xmlDoc.query('/row[1]') as cc
from @xmlDoc.nodes('/ROW') AS t(x)
```

And result like this

```
|    ID    |  USER_ID |   NAME  | CNT |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | --- |
| 471869   | 40161    | James   | 2   |
| 482047   | 40836    | Nick    | 2   |
```

But, need to have one more column with the contents of the entire row, like this

```
| ID       | USER_ID  | NAME    | CNT | ROW                                                      |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | --- | -------------------------------------------------------- |
| 471869   | 40161    | James   | 2   | <ROW ID="471869" USER_ID="40161" NAME="James" CNT="2" /> |
| 482047   | 40836    | Nick    | 2   | <ROW ID="482047" USER_ID="40836" NAME="Nick" CNT="2" />  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `query` method

```
Declare @xmlDoc xml = '
<ROW ID="471869" USER_ID="40161" NAME="James" CNT="2" />
<ROW ID="482047" USER_ID="40836" NAME="Nick" CNT="2" />
'


SELECT x.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS ID,
       x.value('(@USER_ID)[1]', 'int') AS USER_ID,
       x.value('(@NAME)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS NAME,
       x.value('(@CNT)[1]', 'int') AS CNT,
       x.query('.') cc
from @xmlDoc.nodes('/ROW') AS t(x)
```

`cc` type is XML.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa6eff73067c94beabc1f6c15b01d31a)

Comment: TBF they are using query.  They are just not using the correct syntax to bring back the current node.

Comment: sorry, works well, x.query instead of @xmlDoc.query

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
SELECT x.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS ID,
       x.value('(@USER_ID)[1]', 'int') AS USER_ID,
       x.value('(@NAME)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS NAME,
       x.value('(@CNT)[1]', 'int') AS CNT,
       @xmlDoc.query('.') as cc
from @xmlDoc.nodes('/ROW') AS t(x)
```

The . selects the current node.  I highly recommend checking out the XML tutorials on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).  I spent a few years messing with xml on and off but never took the time to dive into it.  It's so much easier once you get your head around how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Good example in here: [selecting individual xml node using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718611/selecting-individual-xml-node-using-sql/67400092#67400092)

```
 Declare @xmlDoc xml = '
    <ROW ID="471869" USER_ID="40161" NAME="James" CNT="2" />
    <ROW ID="482047" USER_ID="40836" NAME="Nick" CNT="2" />
    '
    
    
    SELECT x.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS ID,
           x.value('(@USER_ID)[1]', 'int') AS USER_ID,
           x.value('(@NAME)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS NAME,
           x.value('(@CNT)[1]', 'int') AS CNT,
           x.query('.') as EntireXmlRow
    from @xmlDoc.nodes('/ROW') AS t(x)
```